# Who wrote the eighteenth century song "The Topers"?

Tags: identification-request, poetry

'The Topers' is a limerick-like "song" appearing on [pages 236–237](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_British_Minstrel_and_National_Melodi/NrAwAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA236) of *The British Minstrel, and National Melodist: A Collection of the Most Esteemed and Popular English, Scottish, and Irish Songs, Duets, Catches, Chorusses, Glees, and Comic Recitations; Including All Dibdin's Admired Productions*, Volume 1. Here's the second stanza:

> I heard of a fop,
>         That drank whole tankards,
>     Styl’d himself the prince of sots:
> But I say now, hang
>         Such silly drunkards,
>     Melt their flagons, break their pots.
> My friend and I did join
> For a cellar full of wine,
>     And we drank the vintner out of door;
> We drank it all up
> In a morning, at a sup
>     And greedily rov’d about for more.

Is it possible to determine the authorship of these lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: The identity of the author is lost to history.

The earliest publication of the song was in [*A Collection of Old Ballads*, volume III (1725), pages 145–147](https://archive.org/details/collectionofoldb03philrich/page/n185/mode/2up), under the title ‘Bacchus Overcome’. The anonymous editor of this collection did not give any sources for the collected works, but the appeal to the reader at the end of volume I gives us a clue:

> If any Admirer of old Ballads has any scarce ones by him, Copies of which he would have preserved, he is desired to send them directed to Mr. *Roberts*† near the *Oxford Arms* in *Warwick-Lane*, and at the same time if he pleases, Directions where the Songs should be return’d, after the Compiler of this Collection has taken a Copy of them.
>
> <sub>Anon, ed.‡ (1723). [*A Collection of Old Ballads*, volume I, p. 288](https://archive.org/details/collectionofoldb01philrich/page/n339/mode/2up). London: J. Roberts.</sub>
>
> <sub>† The publisher, not the editor. ‡ The editor is sometimes identified as [Ambrose Philips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrose_Philips) but I believe that Lillian de la Torre Bueno has sufficiently exploded that conjecture: see her 1935 paper ‘[Was Ambrose Philips a Ballad Editor?](https://doi.org/10.1515/angl.1935.1935.59.252)’.</sub>

Ballads were a popular form of literature in the seventeenth century, originally printed on a single side of a sheet of paper, a format that gave them the name “[broadside ballads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadside_ballad)”. There is a catalog of scans of surviving examples at “[Broadside Ballads Online](http://ballads.bodleian.ox.ac.uk)”, hosted by the Bodleian Library. For example, here’s ‘The Jovial Crew’, c. 1670, which should give an idea of the format. The sheet is about 325 mm × 225 mm, a little bigger than modern A4.

[image: Yellowed sheet of paper with ragged edges, in three printed columns. The title ‘The Jovial Crew’ with the ‘w’ printed as ‘vv’ spans the first two columns. There is a woodcut of three men around a table. Two are sitting, with black broad-brimmed hats. The thrd is standing, dressed in doublet and house with a ruff and a large feather-plumed hat, smoking a pipe with a long stem. The text of the ballad begins “Come let’s to the Tavern there’s nothing so sweet” and continues for eight stanzas of eight lines each.]

‘The Jovial Crew’ is typical of broadside ballads in bearing the printer’s name (see bottom right) but not the author’s. So even if the original broadside for ‘Bacchus Overcome’ had survived, we would probably not be any the wiser about the authorship. But a look at various catalogs of ballads, for example the one at the [Vaughan Williams Memorial Library](https://www.vwml.org/search?q=piss-pots&is=1), shows no surviving examples of ‘Bacchus Overcome’ prior to *A Collection of Old Ballads* in 1725.

Comment: Modest men need not take credit for their 'stylish' work? No, I understand, it was different then. The concept of celebrity, if not fame, hadn't quite taken hold.